# Тач по спрайту (Unity 2D)

Tags: unity3d

Есть персонаж (спрайт) и кнопка-стрелка (спрайт) на сцене. Нужно по тачу переместить персонажа. Как это можно реализовать?

```
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
Raycast2D hit = Raycast.Physics(ray.origin, ray.direction);
if(hit){ тач по картинке }
```

Правильно ли это?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Какие твои попытки?

Comment: Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
Raycast2D hit = Raycast.Physics(ray.origin, ray.direction);
if(hit){ тач по картинке }
Правильно ли это?

Comment: @VladimirGordeev: welcome back! </offtopic>

Comment: @Денис нет, это неверно. 2d физика почти всегда (и именно так это в Unity) обрабатывает только столкновения в 2d плоскости, то есть в XY. Соответственно, луч "из камеры" идет в плоскости Z и никогда не столкнется со спрайтом. Нужно повесить на спрайт трехмерный коллайдер и кастовать трехмерный луч. Но, если кнопка - это именно кнопка, и нажать нужно именно на нее, то проще и лучше будет использовать встроенный UI (тот, который называют uGUI или new UI). Там есть уже готовая кнопка, нажатие будет обрабатываться автоматически и ничего кастовать не нужно.

Comment: Надо создать UI Button, в Source Image перенести картинку с кнопкой, верно?

Comment: @Денис, добавляйте уточняющий код в вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: Если я добавлю его в вопрос, будет непонятно, куда он относится

Comment: @Денис Да, нужно именно так. Дальше на компоненте Button добавить действие на событие OnClick() (плюс в самом низу). Там нужно будет выбрать объект, а затем метод или свойство для вызова. Если нужно вызвать метод собственного скрипта, то нужно создать публичный метод. И, если я правильно помню, то не более чем с одним параметром (можно без).

Comment: @Денис: и код (и вопрос из комментария, если контекст нужен) нужно добавлять в вопрос. Вся информация необходимая, чтобы ответить, должна быть в вопросе.

Comment: @Денис Вам дело говорят! Теперь я смог с чистой совестью добавить свои комментарии как ответ, и другим людям будет проще найти информацию, если у них схожая проблема.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, это неправильно. 2d физика почти всегда (и именно так это в Unity) обрабатывает только столкновения в 2d плоскости, то есть в XY. Соответственно, луч "из камеры" идет в плоскости Z и никогда не столкнется со спрайтом. Чтобы все работало, нужно повесить на спрайт трехмерный коллайдер и кастовать трехмерный луч.

Но, если кнопка - это именно кнопка, и нажать нужно именно на нее, то проще и лучше будет использовать встроенный UI (тот, который называют uGUI или new UI). Там есть уже готовая кнопка, нажатие на которую будет обрабатываться автоматически и ничего кастовать не нужно. Для этого надо создать `GameObject->UI->Button`, указать ей в качестве `Source Image` Вашу текстуру. Дальше на компоненте `Button (Script)` добавить действие на событие `OnClick()` (плюс в самом низу). Там нужно будет выбрать объект, а затем компонент, висящий на объекте и его метод или свойство для вызова. Для того, чтобы суметь вызвать метод собственноручно написанного скрипта, метод должен быть публичным и, если я правильно помню, он должен иметь не более одного параметра (можно без).

**Update**
Из кода подписаться на событие нажатия можно так:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonPress : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button Button;

    void OnEnable () {
        Button.onClick.AddListener(ClickHandler);
    }

    void OnDisable () {
        Button.onClick.RemoveListener(ClickHandler);
    }

    void ClickHandler() {
        Debug.Log ("Clicked");
    }
}
```

**Update 2**
Варианты, как отловить *удержание* кнопки:

Вариант 1: повесить на кнопку компонент `EventTrigger`. Добавить на него события `OnPointerDown` и `OnPointerUp`, повесить на них вызовы публичных методов скрипта (может висеть на любом объекте), в которых ставить булевое поле класса в `false` или `true`. И это поле проверять, например, в `Update`. Скрипт будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ButtonHold : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool pressed;

    public void PointerDown()
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    public void PointerUp()
    {
        pressed = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!pressed)
            return;

        Debug.Log("Pressed");
    }
}
```

Вариант 2: сделать скрипт, обрабатывающий эти события автоматически. Скрипт нужно вешать на кнопку.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ButtonHold : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    bool pressed;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pressed = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!pressed)
            return;

        Debug.Log("Pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Смущает то, что кнопка, которую я перенес в Source Image, видна только в режиме Игры, в режиме сцены не видна. Как-то не удобно. Может, с этим можно бороться?

Comment: Она видна и в режиме сцены. Кликните на ней в окне `Hierarchy` 2 раза или просто сильно уменьшите сцену. Просто UI в Unity по умолчанию рисуется в своих собственных координатах. Если же нужно встроить кнопку в саму сцену, то найдите объект `Canvas`, поменяйте там `Render Mode` на `World Space`, задайте позицию и подгоните `Scale`. Вообще, стоит изучить uGUI, если хотите с ним работать. На русском, например, есть [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/246605/), [видеоуроки на youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kByV-tE8sNs).

Comment: а как обратиться к этой кнопке из кода?

Comment: @Денис [Вот](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) описание класса. Добавляете `public UnityEngine.UI.Button Button;` в скрипт, перетаскиваете в инспеткоре туда объект кнопки и обращаетесь к интересующим методам.

Comment: If(Button) {} будет означать, что кнопка нажата?

Comment: @Денис Нет. Это будет проверка `Button` на `null`. Я обновил ответ, теперь там описано, как можно отлавливать нажатие и удержание кнопки в коде.